# How to generate thumbnail for PDF file without downloading it fully?

Tags: ios, pdf, thumbnails

I have to work with external rest API which allows to browse documents library - list docs, get metadata for individual docs and download documents fully or given range. 
Currently we show standard icons for all documents (PDF files on server). 
We want to improve and show thumbnails. 
Is there a way of extracting thumbnail of cover page from PDF without reading whole file? Something similar to EXIF maybe? Client is running on iOS.

Comment: I assume you don't control the server? Generating the icons there would probably be best.

Comment: Yes, we dont have control over server. So we can't pre-generate thumbnails on backend, instead we basically need somehow to use HTTP Range to get as little as possible out of these 30-40 Mb documents to generate thumbnail.

Comment: Well, you can definitely use Apple's Core Graphics PDF rendering, but I don't know of any way of using that on a partial PDF, or knowing how much of a PDF to download. You could always set up a separate server to generate and serve thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I fully understand your environment and your limitations.

However, if you can retrieve a 'given range' of a remote document, then it's easy to just retrieve page 1. (You can only retrieve parts of PDF documents which will successfully render if they are "web optimized" a.k.a. "linearized".)

However, nowadays most PDFs do no longer contain thumbnails which could be retrieved. Adobe software (as well as other PDF viewers) do create the page previews on the fly.

So you must retrieve the first page first.

Then Ghostscript can generate a "thumbnail" from this page. Command for Linux/Unix/MacOSX:

```
 gs \
   -o thumb.jpg \
   -sDEVICE=jpeg \
   -g80x120 \
   -dPDFFitPage \
    firstpage.pdf
```

Command for Windows:

```
 gswin32c.exe ^
   -o thumb.jpg ^
   -sDEVICE=jpeg ^
   -g80x120 ^
   -dPDFFitPage ^
    firstpage.pdf
```

For this example...

- ...the thumbnail filetype will be JPEG. You can change this to PNG (`-sDEVICE=pngalpha`, or `=png256` or `=png16m`).
- ...the thumbnail size will be `80x120` pixel; change it however you need.

Comment: As I said client is iOS application, that is users using iOS app to browse this remote documents repository. See my clarifications above in comments to question. At this point I think we will need some library, it seems PDF files are very complex to try and parse them with our own code  :(